# Have got any (something): singular or plural?

Tags: grammar

I'm uncertain if the following sentence is correct:
**Have you got any pet?** 
Searching for straight questions with "have got" and "any" I've found the noun sometimes as singular, sometimes as plural. Which is grammatically correct?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Have you got any" is generally followed by the plural. Or, an "uncountable noun" like beer or water or ice cream where the singular functions as a plural also.

> Have you got any pet?

Should be

> Have you got any pets?